# SSAS Tabular local access issue but can connect from other servers

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

This was the second time this issue was happening. after a server restart, I couldn't connect to the SSAS tabular model through SSMS with neither my own username (admin) nor the service account.

However, we could all connect to the model from other servers in the network.

The icon changes to this as well :

[image]

after restarting the service a few times and restarting the server and running CHKDSK \R on all drives and getting to nowhere, it gets fixed by itself.

We are really concerned as we cannot find the root cause of the issue and don't want this to happen when we go live with the project. any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure when you are trying to connect to SSAS or SQL locally that you open SSMS with **Run as Administrator**. My assumption is that your account has been given access through the local Windows Administrators group (rather than through direct permissions on your username or through different group permissions). When that is the case, Run as Administrator is required to utilize those local Administrators group permissions on the local server. This is not the case when connecting remotely to a server.

Comment: Thanks Greg, let's say that's the case for us trying to connect to the SSAS model locally. how would that affect the service account used in PowerBI dashboard connections to SSAS? the main problem is when we can't connect to the server locally, the PowerBI dashbaords can't connect to SSAS either.

Comment: @Ariox66 feel free to edit the question with screenshots of how you are connecting as a service account. And include screenshots showing the service account has permissions to SSAS